# QueryDSL projections and null values

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

given this query:

```
final List list =
new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(qdevice).leftJoin(qdevice.parentDevice)
.list(Projections.bean(Device.class, qdevice.id, qdevice.parentDevice));
```

(parentDevice is type of Device )

The problem is that the query only return the Device when the parentDevice is not null. Why? How to get any value back? If I take out qdevice.parentDevice from the projection than the result is good.

QueryDsl version is 3.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this

```
QDevice device = QDevice.device;
QDevice parentDevice = new QDevice("parentDevice");
List<Device> list = new JPAQuery(entityManager)
    .from(device)
    .leftJoin(device.parentDevice, parentDevice)
    .list(Projections.bean(Device.class, device.id, parentDevice));
```

The reference to `qdevice.parentDevice` in `list` might be treated as an inner join, since you don't relate it to the left join.